# Are bears more attracted to menstruating females?

Tags: safety, bears, hygiene

People have speculated that women hiking in bear country during their menstrual cycle might increase their chances of a bear encounter. Is this true? What can be done to minimize risk?

Related question: [Handling feminine hygiene on multiple-month treks?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/865/handling-feminine-hygiene-on-multiple-month-treks)

Answer (score 13):

Unless you are dealing with Polar bears the answer is: No.

According to an article on [livescience](http://www.livescience.com/22688-myth-bears-attack-menstruating-women.html):

> Despite campfire fears dating back to at least 1967, **black bears and grizzly bears are not attracted to the odors of menstruation**, according to a recent Yellowstone National Park report.
>
> **Polar bears may be interested in the smell of menstrual blood**, the report found, but bears that roam in North America are not. **Food is a much more important temptation for bears**, according to the findings.

They also add

> *[According to a Yellowstone Park Report]* the report concludes, there is **no evidence of a link between bear attacks and menstruation**. Nevertheless, the Park Service **recommends using tampons instead of external pads** and **unscented menstrual products** to keep potentially appealing odors down.

The [Yellow Stone National Park Service](http://www.nps.gov/yell/) has an [article](https://www.nps.gov/yell/learn/nature/grizzlybear-menstrual-odor.htm) from 2016 dedicated to this subject. Citations can be found on that page.

Comment: that link appears to be broken. This is a cached copy I believe: http://www.yellowstone-bearman.com/menstruation_data.html